# A Database Error Occurred! fixed by db_debug set to false?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I just want to clear the question in my mind. I got an error

```
   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
   Filename: core/Loader.php
   Line Number: 346
```

after reading some of issue about that error I try to set `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` to `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;` and it works!

as I read this in manual of CI Database Configuration

`db_debug - TRUE/FALSE (boolean) - Whether database errors should be displayed.`

I want to know that does really fix the problem or hiding not the error, but if it only hiding it how come it works? I am worried that it may cause future problem.

same question exist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327775/database-connection-settings-with-db-debug-set-as-false%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5D).

any information and ideas is big help and well appreciated.Many Thanks!

Comment: Is that an error or notice?

Comment: Did you try checking the logs or using `var_dump` on `$db` to see any error messages? You'll need messages to diagnose and fix the problem.

Comment: @jerin "A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings." it does not mention, I thinks it not Apache error

Comment: @steve I try to check it later. Now it fixed I just set debug to false, and it seems to work normally.

Comment: if the functionality is working, it will be a notice or warning.Can you paste the full content in the error message?

Comment: @Jerin yeah functionality's fine it is working, this is the full message prompt `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346`

Comment: @kodewrecker - I didn't notice that you had posted the error, sorry.  Anyway I'd still recommend checking the logs, it's surprisingly entertaining.

Comment: @Steve it ok, yeah that is my plan will check it.I just don't want to settle that it is working, I want to know how.maybe some will answer it.(^_^) thanks anyway.

Comment: is it possible that you are connecting to the database directly in your code - which is working - and the settings in application/config/database.php are wrong - which is why you are getting the error??

Comment: @BinaryNights I think no, I am using MCV codeigniter and all I need to alter to connect to database is the database.php of Codeigniter

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;` set to false rather than `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;`

Comment: yeah i could do that but why? any explanation?

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830830/advantages-disadvantages-of-pconnect-option-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

I found why. In my situation, database error because my mysql config in php.ini is not right.

CI works well after I set mysql config in php.ini, like this:

```
[Mysql]
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

If you didn't configure php.ini, the default socket is /var/mysql/mysql.sock, please check it.

I also set $db['default']['db_debug] to FALSE before, it looks ok, but no.
It's just hide the error of mysql config, when I test to read from tables of mysql, I got nothing and didn't know why nothing.
So I debug it, i found because my mysql connection was not established.   :(

Answer (score 0):

Its worked for me

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: How does usage of persistent connections relate to the OPs issue?

Comment: It will disable persistent connection feature of Mysql. You will get error if your hosing server doesn't support persistent connection.